# Error while applying filter on dataframe - PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I need to subtract 10days from run_date and apply filter on dataframe. However on running below code getting the error. - Error: AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`2020-01-10`' given input columns: [cust, activity_day];;\n'Filter (to_date(activity_day#1341, Some(YYYY-MM-DD)) > date_sub(cast(to_date('2020-01-10, Some(YYYY-MM-DD)) as date), 10))\n+- LogicalRDD [cust#1340L, activity_day#1341]\n".

Data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
          (123,"2020-01-01"),
          (123,"2020-01-01"),
          (123,"2019-01-01")
        ],
        ("cust", "activity_day")
    )
```

Code: I need to subtract 10 days from run_date and apply filter on dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

subtract_days=10
run_date = to_date("2020-01-10","YYYY-MM-DD").cast("date")
df.filter(to_date(df["activity_day"],"YYYY-MM-DD") > date_sub(run_date,subtract_days)).show()
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to_date function only works on column attributes. Hence you need to create a column of run_date literal value using `lit` function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

subtract_days=10
run_date = to_date(lit("2020-01-10"),"YYYY-MM-DD")
df.filter(to_date(df["activity_day"],"YYYY-MM-DD") > date_sub(run_date,subtract_days)).show()
```

Comment: thanks Drashti. When I check type for below statements, in both case I get type as pyspark.sql.column.Column. So can you help me understand how these are different? run_day = to_date("2020-01-10","YYYY-MM-DD")
print(type(run_day)) 

run_date = to_date(lit("2020-01-10"),"YYYY-MM-DD")
print(type(run_date))

Comment: That is because to_date function returns column